# Move position of element horizontally/vertically while scrolling down the page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to move elements on a page while scrolling down, it could be either horizontally or vertically and when the elements reach a point on the page like for example the center, I want them to stop and remained fixed. I would preferably like to achieve this without a plugin. Here is an example of what I want to do but this uses stellar.js, how could this be done without the plugin and also stopping the elements at a certain point eg. the center of page. Thanks

Comment: show us what have you tried.

Comment: well I want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/QGd9g/ but the elements stopping at a certain position.